# I want to solve for X in an equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to solve for X in the equation ode1 (Meaning to leave it alone, or that all the values are on the other side of the equal sign) but the answer it gives me includes to then graph it X vs L but the values on L are changing constantly. Please help

````
ode1 = (.003) (2.28*-6) + ((1651 - X)*
     Sin[3 Degree]) + (((2*(2.27766*-6)*Sqrt[.003])/
       Tan[6 Degree])) (Sqrt[.003 + L*Tan[6 Degree]] - 
      Sqrt[.003]) (1651 - X) - 0.9*(5.67*-8)*(.003*3 Degree*L)*X^4 == 0
sol = Solve[ode1, X, {L, 0, 10}]
Plot[sol, {L, 0, 10}]```
````

Comment: I think a piece of your code is missing

Comment: Yes!, so sorry is
ode1=([Sin[3 Degree]) + (((2*(2.27766*-6)*Sqrt[.003])/
       Tan[6 Degree])) (Sqrt[.003 + L*Tan[6 Degree]] - 
      Sqrt[.003]) (1651 - X) - 0.9*(5.67*-8)*(.003*3 Degree*L)*X^4 == 0)
sol = Solve[ode1, X, {L, 0, 10}]
Plot[sol, {L, 0, 10}]

Comment: The solutions may be obtained from `exprs = X /. sol`

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/4999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot the relation between `L` and `X`,we need not solve by hand,just use `ContourPlot`

```
Clear[fun, ode1];
fun = (.003) (2.28*-6) + ((1651 - X)*
      Sin[3 Degree]) + (((2*(2.27766*-6)*Sqrt[.003])/
        Tan[6 Degree])) (Sqrt[.003 + L*Tan[6 Degree]] - 
       Sqrt[.003]) (1651 - X) - 0.9*(5.67*-8)*(.003*3 Degree*L)*X^4 //
    Simplify;
ode1 = fun == 0;
(*Plot3D[fun,{L,0,10},{X,-50,50}]*)
ContourPlot[
 fun == 0, {L, 0, 10}, {X, -50, 50}, FrameLabel -> {L, X}]
```

[image]

If you insist to `Solve` the equation,then we can do this by

```
Clear[fun, ode1, sol];
fun = (.003) (2.28*-6) + ((1651 - X)*
      Sin[3 Degree]) + (((2*(2.27766*-6)*Sqrt[.003])/
        Tan[6 Degree])) (Sqrt[.003 + L*Tan[6 Degree]] - 
       Sqrt[.003]) (1651 - X) - 0.9*(5.67*-8)*(.003*3 Degree*L)*X^4 //
    Simplify;
ode1 = fun == 0;
sol = Solve[ode1, X];
Plot[X /. sol, {L, 0, 10}]
```

[image]